# Finding the maximum attribute in XPath 1.0 subject to additional constraint

Tags: xml, vba, xpath

I think the question is quite clear but here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
    <Criterion>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </Criterion>
    <Criterion>
        <Name>C</Name>
        <Value>3</Value>
    </Criterion>
    <Criterion>
        <Name>D</Name>
        <Value>4</Value>
    </Criterion>
    <Criterion>
        <Name>B</Name>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </Criterion>
</Root>
```

I'm very new to this but from other answers I know how to find the Criterion with the maximum Value:

```
//Root/Criterion[not(../Criterion/Value > Value)]
```

Which gives me

```
<Criterion>
    <Name>D</Name>
    <Value>4</Value>
</Criterion>
```

As expected. But I want to be able to add an additional constraint, such as "find the Criterion with the highest Value which is less than 3". For this example I would expect it to return

```
<Criterion>
    <Name>B</Name>
    <Value>2</Value>
</Criterion>
```

because this contains the highest Value which is not higher than 3. I've tried a few ideas that seemed like they would work but none of them have; I was hoping I could do it in one or maybe two commands. Does anybody know a simple way of doing this? Unfortunately I'm using VBA and so I'm restricted to using XPath 1.0, and as per the example the elements are not necessarily sorted into any particular order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another condition to the predicate

```
//Root/Criterion[Value <= 3 and not(../Criterion/Value > Value)]
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. That was my first thought but it doesn't work; but I think this proves that it has something to do with how I'm calling it in VBA rather than the XPath command. Without the second condition the code works; as soon as I add the second condition it complains. Looks like I need to dive into the VBA documentation. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Don't tell us "it doesn't work" or "it complains" - tell us precisely how it fails. That way, we have a chance of helping you.

Comment: I've now spent some time looking into the VBA error I'm getting and it turns out that when I add the second condition, nothing is getting returned. It seems to be that the two conditions applied together give nothing, because the maximum for the whole set is not less or equal to 3 (it's 4). I think what I want to do is apply the <=3 condition, and then apply the max condition to the result, rather than trying to apply them both to the same set. I'm not sure how to construct that command, though.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the two conditions are not independent. Why not move to XPath 2.0 rather than doing contortions in XPath 1.0? But you could try: `//Root/Criterion[Value <= 3 and not(../Criterion/Value[. <= 3] > Value)]`

Comment: Thanks very much Michael, that seems to work perfectly! Unfortunately my hands are pretty much tied to using VBA, and as far as I know there is no XPath 2.0 implementation for that. Thank you very much for your help though, this should do nicely!

Comment: I thought it was fairly easy to call .NET libraries from VBA, and that means you can have the full power of XPath 3.1 if you download Saxon for .NET.

Comment: I'm sure you are right, but I can also say that IT in my place of work is so backward that trying to use anything beyond MS Office is almost certainly going to be more trouble than it's worth. Thanks for the tip though, I'll look into it for the longer term.

Comment: I thought dinosaur shops like that usually banned their staff from using sites like StackOverflow...

Comment: You are exactly right...all I can say is thank god for mobile data